# How can I run weekly reports from my stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting

I would like to run weekly reports (from Monday to Sunday) based on a timesheets table, so that I can see what type of jobs are being requested and booked.

In the `timesheets` table there is a `start_dtm` and `end_dtm`

How would I run a query to check for Start and End of the week?

**edit: I have the following code which grabs the start and end date:**

```
---------------------------------
--Please set your appropriate values for @REPORT_DATE and @WEEK_BEGINING
DECLARE @REPORT_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_BEGINING VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @REPORT_DATE = '2012-03-16T00:00:00'
SELECT @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 1
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'TUESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 2
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'WEDNESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 3
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'THURSDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 4
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'FRIDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 5
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SATURDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 6
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SUNDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @WEEK_START_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_END_DATE DATETIME
--GET THE WEEK START DATE
SELECT @WEEK_START_DATE = @REPORT_DATE - (DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE) - 1)
--GET THE WEEK END DATE
SELECT @WEEK_END_DATE = @REPORT_DATE + (7 - DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE))
PRINT 'Week Start: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_START_DATE)
PRINT 'Week End: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_END_DATE)
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Need a bit more detail here. Why do you want to check for start and end of week?

Comment: You asked for more detail but if you actually read the first paragraph you will see the outline to what i wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this SQL to determine Monday and Friday of the week of a given date

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @Date date = GETDATE() --give a date here

SELECT
    @Date [SelectedDate], 
    DATENAME(dw, @Date) [SelectedWD],
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) [WeekStart],
    DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date)) [WeekStartWD],
    DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)+2), @Date) [WeekEnd],
    DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)+2), @Date)) [WeekEndWD]

**Example output**
SelectedDate    SelectedWD  WeekStart   WeekStartWD WeekEnd     WeekEndWD
2012-03-16      Friday      2012-03-12  Monday      2012-03-16  Friday
```

**--------------------------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------------------------**
**USAGE**

This gives you the results for 1 week (only weekdays)

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @Date date = GETDATE() --give a date here
DECLARE @WeekStart Date, @WeekEnd Date

select @WeekStart = DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date),
@WeekEnd = DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)+2), @Date)

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd
```

Comment: You may use the values in `WeekStart`and `WeekEnd` columns as your boundry values. **For example:** WHERE MyDate BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd

Comment: Could you explain your code to me please? Im a bit of noobie. Sorry

Comment: Yes, so if i have a load of timesheets i can use this filter based on the now() date?? then it will find the week beggining and filter the results??

Comment: if you use getdate(), it will find the start and end dates for this week. if you give a date from last week it will give the start and end dates for last week

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how you write the query will depend on your requirements - when you run the report etc. Investigate the [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function and/or the [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) keyword.